# Yaws server is not accessible outside of local network

Tags: erlang, yaws

I am trying to host erlang Yaws web server on my Raspberry Pi. 
I am using no-ip as dynamic DNS.
My router is Thomson ST780. On the router I have made port forwarding from port 50001 to port 8081 on my Raspberry Pi.
My server is accessible from within the local network only and shows index.yaws as expected. However, I want it to be accessible from the internet. I believe the problem lies in Yaws config, because I have disabled firewall on my router, and also firewall is disabled on Pi.

The Yaws config part that I believe is wrongly configured looks like this:

```
<server my_application_name.no-ip.org>
 port = 8081
 listen = 0.0.0.0
 docroot = /home/pi/erl/airport
 dir_listing = false
 auth_log = true
 statistics = true
 appmode = <cgi-bin, yaws_appmod_cgi>
</server>
```

I have also tried adding

```
<auth> allow = all </auth>
```

and putting local IP address in listen part and it is still not working.

Can anybody see the problem with this configuration?

I am also using the same way of port forwarding on my router for SSH and SSH is accessible from the internet.

EDIT: The install that I have made is local_install, as recommended here: http://yaws.hyber.org/configuration.yaws and perhaps that might be a problem.

Comment: Ok so it's not a Yaws issue. It is Internet Explorer on Windows Phone 7.5 issue or my ISP issue. Because yesterday I was trying to reach the page from my 3G network on Windows Phone and it was not reachable so I thought that it is a configuration issue.
Today I tried the same from my company and the page is reachable. It is also reachable from iPhone, but it is still not reachable from my  Windows Phone.

Comment: You may want to use a tool like `tcpdump` to verify where your packets are flowing and what headers they contain.

Comment: I have solved the problem by opening port 80 on router and forwarding requests to Yaws on RPI on port 8081. It was not a Yaws configuration problem. It seems that the problem is in my ISP and  Squid proxy that it uses which does not allow, for some reason, requests to port 50001 that I have opened. I believe it would be too time consuming to communicate with ISP asking them to open access to my port.